# Salesforce mobile sdk iOS back button issue

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am using salesforce mobile sdk in my native iOS application and when the login screen is launched by the sdk it doesn't show any back button. Is there any way i can get a back or cancel button on the login screen so that user can come back to on boarding screen?﻿

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.
If you have the source code of SDK then you need to add a new property in SFLoginviewcontroller which will give you call back to back button press.

In 
SFLoginviewcontroller-(BOOL)shouldShowBackButton()

Forcefully 
Return YES